# random flash cs5.5 as3 error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i am creating a menu in flash, and when i try to test the file i get the following error:

```
"ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable TCMText is not defined."
```

one website said that it was because there were TLF textboxes in the file, but i fixed that, but keep getting the error.

the code i am using for the buttons is as follows:

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void{

gotoAndStop(5);

}
```

any ideas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `textLayout.swc` file from your project folder.

Comment: Go to the folder where you exported the *.swf file, and remove the file named `textLayout.swc`